" ...syntactically, being rather a matter of pragmatics, dependent... " - Can we delete 'being rather' in the parenthetical?

In the non-parenthetical construction the matrix verb and its subject
may also be backgrounded, but this is not signalled syntactically,
being rather a matter of pragmatics, dependent on context and the
content of the subordinate clause.

According to my reading summary, if only a single noun is used as an parenthetical, the noun generally serves as an appositive function, or as a Resumptive and Summative function.
But the noun here does not fall into my summary, it functions like a subject complement. So, is it true that when a parenthetical with only a noun functions as a subject complement, there usually is a copula before it?

Consider:

The leaking pipes in the basement were not touched by the carpenter, being rather a matter for the plumber.

The participial clause ascribes to the noun-phrase subject in the matrix clause ("the leaking pipes in the basement") the attribute "a matter for the plumber".  The participial clause there presents a reason for the predicate "were not touched by the carpenter", with "rather" being anchored semantically to the negation.

You cannot remove “being rather” without it  becoming grammatically incorrect and (more importantly) hard to comprehend. “A matter of pragmatics” could be used on its own as a parenthetical noun with no copula, but only if you had not placed a contradicting phrase (beginning with “but”) in between, separating it from its subject. You could use something like “It is” as the copula in place of “being rather,” you just need to clarify that you are returning to describing what the subject is, otherwise it becomes hard to read.
